# sugarcrm editview coding help for newbi

Tags: java, php, html, sugarcrm

I have an older version of sugarcrm 4.5 running.

Dont brake that aint broken.

I have a script i wrote that adds 30 days from current date to expected close date when creating a new opportunity, but the problem is everytime you edit the opportunity it adds 30 days, and not just when its is new. How do i tel Sugar to only look for new. this is in editview.php not a logic hook as i want to display the date in the field when creating.

Heres my code

```
var currentTime = new Date();
document.getElementsByName('date_closed')[0].value = (year = currentTime.getFullYear())+'-'+(month = currentTime.getMonth() + 2)+'-'+(day = currentTime.getDate());
```

regards

Answer (score 0):

This should be done with a before save logic hook - you can test to see if the record has an id in the hook. If it has no id then you can assume its a new record.

More information on logic hooks can be found here (you are using a very old version of SugarCRM so not everything in this documentation will apply)

http://developers.sugarcrm.com/docs/OS/5.2/-docs-Developer_Guides-Developer_Guide_5.2-DevGuide%205.2.1.47.html